# Back Button being created on my navigation view controller, not able to hide it

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a Navigation View Controller A that leads to Controller B and then Controller C. Controller B is a login screen, so once the user logs in, the user gets taken to Controller C. What I initially wanted to do was have the back button on Controller C, take the user back to Controller A (because the user is already logged in, there is no point in having the back button take the user back to the Controller B which is the login screen). I have succeeded in doing this except for one peculiar bug which I cant seem to fix. When transitioning from Controller C to Controller A, a back button gets added to the navigation bar on Controller A! Controller A never had a back bar to begin with, this is driving me nuts!

I have tried entering in all the following code in viewWillAppear method:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

None of these are taking away the back button! I have no clue what to do, any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated I am still a noob.

Comment: How are you taking them back to Controller A?

Comment: Well in Controller C I have this following code to take them back     -(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the popToRoot in the `viewWillDisappear` method. I assume that you have some function that gets called when the user is all done with the registration process in Controller C. At the end of that method you need to put `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

Putting it in `viewWillDisappear` and especially before the `[super viewWillDissappear]` method is most likely causing the problem.

EDIT:

Try structuring your viewWillDisappear method like this, with the super call first:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

EDIT:

Well, I have got it to *kind* of work. If you don't need to push anymore views onto it after you have popped from Controller C this will work. Update the -viewWillDisappear in Controller C to look like this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]] animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: There is not registration process in Controller C, that is Controller B where the user logs in. In controller C I am just trying to have the "back" butto which appears on the navigation bar take the user back to Controller A when the user taps on it. I have succeeded in doing this by implementing the code above but clearly I did something wrong because the back button now shows up on View Controller A as well. Where should I put that code if not in in the viewWillDisappear method, that is the only way I have been able to succesfully pop back to root so far.

Comment: Oooo I see what your trying to do now. Try structuring your viewWillDisappear message (see updated answer).

Comment: This did work, however I just noticed that now View Controller B's back button disappears

Comment: Any clue as to why its making view Controller B's back button disappear now?

Comment: Yea I know VC B back button disappears. I'm not really sure as to why it's happening. I think that by setting the view controllers before the animation has completed, the root view controller is somehow getting messed up. The only other way that I've seen it done is by subclass UINavigationController and overriding some methods. Not sure if its legal by apple or not.

Comment: What I would do is that instead of having a back button, create a new UIBarButtonItem and set it in place of the back button. From a UI design respect this is the way to go. Pressing back in a navigation stack the user assumes they are going to the view just before the current one. Have a new button breaks that expectation and makes it more intuitive.